# can we build a dynamic url in laravel, which can include the blade file dynamicly

Tags: laravel

Iam trying to build an easy method to build a `laravel` project. I got from articles that we should build `controller` and `blade` file
for example this command `php artisan make:livewire Admin.CourseList`
if we had a lot of page it's going to be lot of file,

so i hava a questions can we just build one controller to use in a lot of `blade` file, the idea is making dynamic `url`, then the `url` detected in `controller`, `controller` get data from `url` to fetch the `blade` file.

**Iam trying to use this method**

`Route::get('master/{fileis}', Master::class);  ( my route )`

```
<?php
// master controller
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;

class Master extends Component 
{
   public function index ($field)
   {
      return view('livewire.admin.$filed');
   }
}
```

I wish that when `url` with `$field` are going to be the file name.

So the effect i wish for example `mywebsite.com/master/login-file`, this url going to fetch `login-file.blade.` but it's didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a many typo in your question, but i got what you mean.

Try This.

```
// in route
Route::get('/{$field}', [Master::class, 'index']);

// master index()
public function index ($field)
{
   // `double quote` for `var` inside `string`
   return view("livewire.admin.$field");
}
```

Remember to create necessary `view` or add `if` with `logical` `View::exists('your_view')` in your `view` call

**EDIT: in LARAVEL LIVEWIRE**

I'll give you some picture.

run `php artisan make:livewire admin.course`

```
// in route
Route::livewire('/course/{course}', 'admin.course');

// in Course.php
class Course extends Component
{
    public $course;

    public function mount($course)
    {
        // init course in mount cycle
        $this->course = $course;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        // insert `public $coursea` to your `view`
        return view("livewire.admin.$this->course", [
            'course' => $this->course,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's works great, sorry for my bad Englishes. Thanks for your answer

Comment: but it's didn't run in livewire, @atma . when I'd like to make it work in livewire 
class Master extends Component
{

    public function render ($field)
    {
        
        return view("livewire.admin.$field");
    }

}

it shows error : Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $field ]]

Comment: save `route` param in **public** `variable` in `mount` function, see my edit